# convert html textbox with searchstring to bootstrap button addon?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone give me some advice on how to transform this:

```html
<p>Find Entry/Exit: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @placeholder = "Search..." }) <input class="btn btn-danger btn btn-xs" type="submit" value="Search" />`
```

to bootstrap button add on? 
I want to do something like this:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

, but I don't know where to put "Search String" in it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did something else with it, so this topic is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="SearchString" name="SearchString" placeholder="Search String"/>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please make sure to add bootstrap css and JS libraries in your page.

**[Reference to bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**

Comment: It does not work on searching for an item, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: did you got any error? Is it a normal form post or an AJAX call? make sure you have handled the button click event propertly with correct selector and if you get any error in console, let me know

Comment: No it didn't show any error, I tried with the bootstrap reference and it did not work. It's a normal form, I tried it from here: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: What is the issue exactly? is your form gettng posted? If yes are you getting this value at the backend?

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't retrieve the value that I give it to retrieve, For example if I want to search for Sam it doesn't retrieve nothing.